# Message display in subform in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am creating one subForm from Main form on button click event of Main Form.Now On subForm I have added one button named 'OK'.ModalResult property of Button set to mrOK. On Ok button click i want to peform some validations. If there is some error i want to show it on subform and should focus on the error filed of SubForm. But I am able to show error message and after error msg displayed Subform closes and main form will be displayed. Below is part of code. Plz help me.

```
result:= frmAddField.showModal= mrOK; // subForm

procedure TfrmAddField.btnOKClick(Sender:TObject);
begin
  if edit1.text = '' then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Error',mtWarning,[mbOK],0);
    edit1.setfocus;
    break;
  end;
 // to be continued
end;
```

Comment: [Error] SubForm.pas(53): BREAK or CONTINUE outside of loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Break` is not what you want here. Use `Exit` if you want to leave the current function or procedure. Also make sure that you only set the modal result if you want the form to close, in your example:

```
procedure TfrmAddField.btnOKClick(Sender:TObject);
begin
  if edit1.text = '' then
  begin
    MessageDlg('Error',mtWarning,[mbOK],0);
    edit1.setfocus;
    Exit;
  end;     
 // to be continued
 ModalResult := mrOK;          // validation worked, close the form!
end;
```

Comment: I know it has the same effect, but I think that Abort conveys the meaning better that exit.

Comment: actually having break outside of a loop should not compile

Answer (score 5):

Set the ModalResult property on the Button back to mrNone. Alter your event handler:

```
procedure TfrmAddField.btnOKClick(Sender:TObject); 
begin 
  if edit1.text = '' then 
  begin 
    MessageDlg('Error',mtWarning,[mbOK],0); 
    edit1.setfocus; 
  end else
    ModalResult := mrOK;
end;
```